# Which library to install on target?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I’m new to Qt Quick. So, This might sound like a dumb question. But I’m struggling with this.
I want to develop a complete UI for my embedded system using Qt Quick. So, I need QML to run my system.
Now, which library to install on my target embedded linux system.
I ‘ve seen this page : http://qt-project.org/downloads but it shows the library with 228MB! which will float my system size abnormally. I expect my system to be around 50MB only! I think this comes with lot of things which I may not want.
I may use qml, for internet browsing purpose parts of webkit (webkit module for qtquick)
xml.
So, Can you please help me which to install? & how??

Thanks & Regards
inblueswithu

Answer (score 1):

Check http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-install.html for a initial documentation.

Please note, that this will install everything, meaning all Qt modules. You might be able to strip some of them away, also you might now need all image plugins. However, as a start this should work for you.